# Destination view in segue gives error in property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, segue

I am trying to pass a custom object to a new view's property though it gives an error because it cannot find the "setter" for the property.

When I select a row in my table this method is called:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.actionIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SELECTED_PERSON sender:self];
}
```

Next:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:CREATE_EDIT_PERSON]) {
        PersonDebtViewController *editPerson = [segue destinationViewController];
        editPerson.editPerson = self.oweMePeople[self.actionIndexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SELECTED_PERSON]) {
        EmailViewController *emailPerson = [segue destinationViewController];
        emailPerson.selectedPerson = self.oweMePeople[self.actionIndexPath.row];
    }

    self.actionIndexPath = nil;
}
```

It is in the emailPerson.selectedPerson =... it goes wrong.

I have declared the property in the destinationview:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface EmailViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) Person *selectedPerson;

@end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: Does your edit works ?

Comment: @KerrM: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setSelectedPerson:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed39daa090'

Comment: @NickCatib: Yes it does. Very strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to set your view controller to a `EmailViewController` in Storyboard. Your error is telling you:

```
[UIViewController setSelectedPerson:]
```

Trying to send the message `setSelectedPerson:` to an instance of `UIViewController`

Comment: For god sake... Yes I forgot.. Thank you very much! I will accept the answer when I am allowed (4min). :)